# I'm trying to change the individual style of the options of a select dropbar and make the corners rounded but can't do it anyone know how?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind to style but am not sure how to change it in CSS either heres the code for the select

```
<select class="h-8 w-24 bg-neutral-900 cursor-pointer inline-flex align-middle p-1 m-4 font-bold text-neutral-400 hover:text-red-800 active:text-red-900 focus:text-red-800 transition ease-in-out duration-300 carret-black">
 <option>red</option>
  <option>green</option>
  <option>blue</option>          
</select>
```

I can't change it by adding class to the options and doing it that way and haven't been able to find how to change the options background, text colour and rounding the edges of the dropdown menu.

So it looks like [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ocA1.jpg) and i want it to look more like [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhaw9.jpg)

I've also tryed doing it through CSS to no avail either any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you cannot style the select options with CSS. What you can do is create your own select component. To get everything, like accessibility, working well can be tricky though.

You could take the [Headless UI listbox](https://headlessui.dev/vue/listbox) as a starting point. This is an unstyled custom select, created to style with Tailwind CSS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah that helps heaps thanks, i hadn't heard of this before it's going to help me out with lots of things thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is no accessible options container (wrapper) element in the Dom in order to change it's style.
you can create your own dropdown :

```
    <!-- Component Start -->
    <div class="relative">
        <button class="flex items-center h-8 pl-3 pr-2 border border-black focus:outline-none">
            <span class="text-sm leading-none">
                Dropdown
            </span>
            <svg class="w-4 h-4 mt-px ml-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
        </button>
        <div class="absolute flex flex-col w-40 mt-1 border border-black shadow-lg">
            <a class="flex items-center h-8 px-3 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200" href="#">Item 1</a>
            <a class="flex items-center h-8 px-3 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200" href="#">Item 2</a>
            <a class="flex items-center h-8 px-3 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200" href="#">Item 3</a>
            <a class="flex items-center h-8 px-3 text-sm hover:bg-gray-200" href="#">Item 4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Component End  -->
```